# How to fill a polygon with image OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv, textures

My polygon has 4 angles, but it is not a rectangle. It is some convex polygon which shape is constantly changing. With `Core.fillConvexPoly` you can fill it with color. I would like to place there some image. So that it will be textured.

I am using OpenVC for Android. Does anyone have any insight?

Thank you!

-epsilon

Comment: How do you want to "place" the image? Stretch/distort a rectangular image to completely be placed in the polygpn or stamp out a part of the image with the polygon's shape?

Comment: @Micka So imagine this polygon http://mathforum.org/sum95/math_and/poly/polygon.gif and any rectangular image. I want my image to be always not rotated, but it will be weirdly scaled throughput the polygon in order to fit it.

Comment: Ok, findHompgraphy and warpPerspective will be the way to go!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you first need to find transformation matrix that projects your texture corners

`{(0,0), (w,0), (w,h), (0,h)}`

to corresponding polygon corners by using [getPerspectiveTransform](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=warpperspective#getperspectivetransform);

and then use [warpPerspective](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=warpperspective#warpperspective) to fit the texture into your polygon.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I am not that experienced in linear algebra. Could you elaborate a bit more? Sample code? Assume I have 4 org.opencv.core.Points

Comment: It is like you are doing inverse of this: http://opencv-code.com/tutorials/automatic-perspective-correction-for-quadrilateral-objects/. And for code, sorry I did not use android bundle of opencv before. googling may help you

Comment: elaboration: first method will create a matrix that you will use in second. you will then get your transformed texture. no big algebra going on there, opencv does it for you. finally you need to blend your original image with the resultant texture.

Comment: Thank you! I will try that. Also, C++ OpenCV code is fine too. (s if you could give some sample it would be great) The android version is just a wrapper around the original c++ code.

Comment: http://opencvexamples.blogspot.com/2014/01/perspective-transform.html#.VGdFRfmsV8E

Comment: Thanks you for the response. How would you add transparency (alpha value) to the image inside the polygon?

Comment: You need to make both image and transformed texture 4 channels type; then use addWeighted method to get what you need

Comment: oh no, you dont need that

Comment: Ok, thats good :) Is there any sample code how can I do this without modifying the source?